# Can't connect to Amazon MQ broker using NMS

Tags: .net, activemq-classic, amazon-mq, apache-nms

I created a broker on AWS where I have a list of endpoints like this:

```
amqp+ssl://b-***-1.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:5671
ssl://b-***-1.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:61617
stomp+ssl://b-***-1.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:61614
mqtt+ssl://b-***-1.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:8883
```

I tried to call the endpoints in a .NET application by using Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ, but I always get the error:

```
Apache.NMS.NMSConnectionException: 'No IConnectionFactory implementation found for connection URI: amqps://b***-1.mq.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:5671
```

This is my application:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Apache.NMS;
using Apache.NMS.Util;
using Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ;

namespace Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Test
{
  public class TestMain
  {
    public static void Main()
    {
        Uri connecturi = new Uri("amqp+ssl://b-***-1.mq.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:5671");
       
        Console.WriteLine("About to connect to " + connecturi);

        IConnectionFactory factory = new NMSConnectionFactory(connecturi);
```

.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I opened the ports for inbound traffic and can access the broker console.

I also tried `amqp://b-***-1.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:5671` but without luck.

I can succesfully interact with a local server using:

```
Uri connecturi = new Uri("tcp://localhost:61616?wireFormat.tightEncodingEnabled=true");
```

Is there something missing?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to connect to an AMQP endpoint from the .NET [NMS.ActiveMQ](https://activemq.apache.org/components/nms/providers/activemq/downloads/) openwire protocol client which will definitely not work.  You need to either use an .NET AMQP client such as the [NMS.AMQP client](https://activemq.apache.org/components/nms/providers/amqp/downloads/) or point the client you already have at the Openwire port (61617) and use the proper URI for that client which is likely ("ssl://:") and of course make an needed configuration changes needed for the client to find the right SSL certificates.